# Hiding elements with a specified id

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have two different divs

```
var promptContent = $('<div id="errorr">').addClass("formErrorContent").html(promptText).appendTo(prompt);
var arrow = $('<div id="errorrarrow">').addClass("formErrorArrow");
```

I want to use their id in javascript like this

```
  function windowclose()
{
    document.getElementById('add_project').style.display="none";
    document.getElementById('blanket').style.display="none";
    document.getElementById('errorr').style.display="none";
    document.getElementById('errorrarrow').style.display="none";

//     $("#blanket").fadeIn("none");
//        $("#add_project").fadeIn("none");
}
```

But here it hides only the 1st div. I want to hide all the divs with the same id. How can I do this?

Comment: What does this have to do with CodeIgniter or PHP?

Comment: Only ONE div (HTMLElement) can have ID of certain value! You can't have two or more divs with id "errorr"!!! Use class attribute to group them by a literal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though using the same ID on many elements is semantically invalid, you could do it in a single jQuery line.

```
$('#errorr, #errorrarrow').hide();
```

Answer (score 3):

Choose between to use name or id:

`getElementsByName('errorr')` searches in the DOM an element named `errorr`

`getElementById('errorr')` searches in the DOM an element with the id equals to `errorr`;

Try to change your code:

```
document.getElementsByName('errorr').style.display="none";
document.getElementsByName('errorrarrow').style.display="none";
```

to

```
document.getElementById('errorr').style.display="none";
document.getElementsById('errorrarrow').style.display="none";
```

also note that a DOM must have all unique IDs (as rule)

**UPDATE:**

Well, if you need to hide a set of divs I usually add at all of them a class like `.element-to-hide`:

```
<div id="asd" class="element-to-hide">...
<div id="lol" class="element-to-hide">...
<div id="foo" class="element-to-hide">...
```

Ant after just a touch of `jQuery`:

```
$('.element-to-hide').each(function(){
  $(this).hide();
});
```

Hope this help