# javascript hidden div made visible - can't find element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I load a page which has a hidden div. Upon clicking one of the "li"s, the contents of the hidden div are loaded into another div called "resultblock". I have a radio button inside the "resultblock" div named "CUSTOM". Upon clicking this radio button, I'd like the 2 textboxes next to it to change from "readonly to editable & then the date format of "yyyy/mm/dd" to be displayed inside the textboxes. I'm trying to achieve this by calling a function eb_tb &. Upn clicking any other radio button other than "CUSTOM", I'd like the textboxes to clear up & go readonly which I'm trying to do with dib_tb function. Neither of these seem to work unfortunately.

Without loading the hidden div into "resultblock" div, the functionality works. It's the loading of items into resultblock which is causing the problem.

"thisFile.php" refers to the filename that the current code resides in. I'm referring to the same file to load the div which is hidden into "resultblock" div.

Here's my code. Could someone please help me spot my mistake?

```
  <html>
       <head>
          <meta charset='utf-8'>
          <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
          <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
          <!--link rel="stylesheet" href="css/revised.css"-->
          <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/dashboard.css">
          <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
          <script type="text/javascript">
             function setDivProps() {
                $('#resultblock').height(594).css({
                   cursor: "auto",
                   backgroundColor: "#A69A74",
                  // backgroundColor: "#FFFFFF",
                   marginLeft: "5%",
                   marginTop: "5%",
                   width: "88%",
                   height: "75%",
                   borderRadius: "25px",
                   border: "2px solid black",
                  // background: "url(image/divpic.jpg)" 
                });
             };

            function radio_check_enable_custom_date_range_text_box() {
                if (document.getElementById('hd_radio_1').checked) {
                    document.getElementById('custom_date_range_id_1').removeAttribute('readonly');
                    document.getElementById('custom_date_range_id_2').removeAttribute('readonly');
                    document.getElementById('custom_date_range_id_1').value = 'yyyy-mm-dd';
                    document.getElementById('custom_date_range_id_2').value = 'yyyy-mm-dd';
                }
            }
            ;


            function radio_check_disable_custom_date_range_text_box() {
                document.getElementById('hd_radio_1').checked == false;
                if (document.getElementById('hd_radio_1').checked === false) {
                    document.getElementById('custom_date_range_id_1').value = '';
                    document.getElementById('custom_date_range_id_2').value = '';
                    document.getElementById('custom_date_range_id_1').setAttribute('readonly', true);
                    document.getElementById('custom_date_range_id_2').setAttribute('readonly', true);
                }
            }
            ;

             $(document).ready(function(){
                $('#cssmenu li').click(function(){
                   $("#cssmenu li").removeClass("active");
                   $(this).addClass("active");
                 });

                $("#page1").click(function(){
                   setDivProps();
                   // $(this).css("background-color","black");
                   $('#resultblock').load('thisFile.php #form_1');
                });

                $("#page2").click(function(){
                   setDivProps();
                   $('#resultblock').load('thisFile.php #form_2');
                });

                $("#page3").click(function(){
                   setDivProps();
                   $('#resultblock').load('thisFile.php #form_3');
                });
             });
       </script>
          <title>DEMO</title>
       </head>
       <body>
          <div>
             <header class="site-header-wrap">
                <div class="site-header">
                   <h1>MY DEMO</h1>
                </div>
             </header>
             <div id='cssmenu'>
                <ul class="uinav">
                   <li class='active'><a id="home1" href='#' ><span>OPTION-1</span></a></li>
                   <li><a id="page1" href="#"><span>OPTION-2</span></a></li>
                   <li><a id="page2" href="#"><span>TOPTION-3</span></a></li>
                   <li><a id="page3" href="#"><span>OPTION-4</span></a></li>  
                </ul>
             </div>
             <div id="div_id_1" style="display: none;">
                <form method="post" action="" id='form_1'>
                  <table id="tbl_format_1">
                      <tr bgcolor="#8F4A11">
                          <td colspan="3" id="table_f_1">
                              <b> TIMELINE </b>
                          </td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                          <td colspan=3>
```

bla bla

Comment: I suspect your problem is that you are creating duplicate IDs on your page. Even though the original div is hidden, the IDs are still there and will be found by `getElementById`.

Comment: Hello jack - Thank you very much. I did think about it some stage but honestly, couldn't figure out if this was the case. Could you please help me with a strategy to figure this out? Something like print all getElementById IDs including those for visible & invisible elements with a console.log kind of thing? The other way out I can think of is, how can I dynamically create  these text boxes or any element & define a listener on it (like a onChange,onClick etc) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the different ways I managed to work out this.

**SOLUTION - 1**

http://forums.asp.net/t/1600445.aspx?To+Hide+multiple+items+having+same+ID+using+Javascript

```
function hideAll(ctrlId)
{
    var Ctrls = document.all(ctrlId);
    for (var i = 0; i<Ctrls.items.length; i++)
    {
          var Ctrl = Ctrls.items(i);
          Ctrl.style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

**SOLUTION - 2**

[Hiding elements with a specified id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6612514/hiding-elements-with-a-specified-id)

UPDATE:

Well, if you need to hide a set of divs I usually add at all of them a class like .element-to-hide:

```
<div id="asd" class="element-to-hide">...
<div id="lol" class="element-to-hide">...
<div id="foo" class="element-to-hide">...
Ant after just a touch of jQuery:

$('.element-to-hide').each(function(){
  $(this).hide();
});
```

Hope this helps others in the same situation as I was in.